# AngularJS, hook URL changing

Tags: angularjs

I have AngularJS application with next route:

```
/user/:userId
```

User opens

```
http://localhost/#/user/1
```

in browser. Then he changes `userId` value from `1` to `2` in URL bar and press enter.

My question is: how to hook this moment and do not reload controller? For example, I just want to show message (or do alert() or console.log()) with new `userId` value on the same page.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the [`'$stateChangeStart'` event](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) and call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the user from actually going to a new view.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // transitionTo() promise will be rejected with 
    // a 'transition prevented' error
});
```

Note, if you are adding this listener inside your controller, you should keep a reference to the deregistration function in order to remove the listener when your scope is destroyed.

```
  var removeListenerFn = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        // transitionTo() promise will be rejected with 
        // a 'transition prevented' error
    }
  );

  $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
    removeListenerFn();
  });
```

Here is a sample Plunker which you can use to test it out: http://plnkr.co/edit/lYfkPuePGv1GlN1sFjW4?p=preview